# Find and replace in same string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string with some words in them, example `a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50`. Now I want to parse this and create another string `a=50 b=2 c=3` which is essentially the same as above except that if the same phrase before the `=` is encountered for the second time the first one is over written with the latest one, so in the end there are only unique phrases on the left of `=`. Here is what I got till now:

```
a="a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50"
o=()

for i in $a
do
    reg=${i%=*}
    if [[ ${o[*]} == *"$reg"* ]]
    then
        o=$(echo ${o[*]} | sed -e "s/\$reg=\S/\$i")
    else
        o+=( $i )
    fi
done
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why is the result `a=5`, not `a=50`?

Comment: Use an associative array whose keys are the words before `=`.

Comment: Did you mean to use double quotes with `sed`?

Comment: Does the ordering matter on the output end?

Comment: nope, that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to keep it simple without using associative arrays. But if I didn't find any other way I would do that.

Comment: Why did you escape the `$` characters in `sed`? That will prevent the variables from being expanded.

Comment: @noMAD: Is it for version-constraint reasons that you're avoiding associative arrays? (If so, that's a legitimate reason for an awk-based solution, perhaps... unless your keys are all valid shell variable names, in which case some other flavors of native shell solutions are also possible).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got no such reason. I just thought avoiding arrays would keep it simple but its clearly not the case. Also, my keys are environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take an entirely different approach, *not* based on regular expressions or string rewriting.

```
declare -A values=( )              # Initialize an associative array ("hash", "map")
while IFS= read -r -d' ' word; do  # iterate over input words, separated by spaces
  if [[ $word = *=* ]]; then       # ignore any word that doesn't have an "=" in it
    values[${word%%=*}]=${word#*=} # add everything before the "=" as a key...
  fi                               # ...with everything after the "=" as a value
done

for key in "${!values[@]}"; do     # Then iterate over keys we found
  value="${values[$key]}"          # ...extract the values for each...
  printf '%s=%s ' "$key" "$value"  # ...and print the pairs.
done
echo                               # When done iterating, print a newline.
```

Because the words are being processed first-to-last through the string, updates take effect before the print loop is reached.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F= -v RS=" |\n" '{a[$1]=$2} END{for (k in a) printf "%s=%s ",k,a[k]}' <<<"a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50"
a=50 b=2 c=3
```

How it works:

- `-F=`

  Set the field separator to be an equal sign.
- `-v RS=" |\n"`

  Set the record separator to be either a space or a newline.
- `a[$1]=$2`

  Update associative array `a` with the latest value.
- `END{for (k in a) printf "%s=%s ",k,a[k]}`

  In no particular order, print out the final values.

#### Using `bash`

Like Charles Duffy's approach, this uses `read -d" "` to parse the string.  This approach, however, uses `IFS="="` to separate names and values.

Two loops are required.  The first gathers the values.  The second reassembles the updated values in the original order:

```
a="a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50"
declare -A b
while IFS== read -d" " name value
do
    b["$name"]="$value"
done <<<"$a "

declare -A seen
while IFS== read -d" " name value
do
    [ "${seen[$name]}" ] || o="$o $name=${b["$name"]}"
    seen[$name]=1
done <<<"$a "
echo "$o"
```

Comment: Nice. The only quibble I have here is that iterating through the string a second time, it reads to me like you could be printing keys twice. Perhaps use a second associative array to track what has and hasn't been printed to avoid that? Retaining order _is_ a nice feature (and one I paid no attention to).

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with perl:

```
echo "a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50" \
  | sed "s/ /\n/g" \
  | perl -e '
my %hash = ();
while(<>){
  $line = $_;
  if($line =~ m/(\S+)=(\S+)/) {
    $hash{$1} = $2;
  }
}
for $key (sort keys %hash) {
  print "$key=$hash{$key}\n";
}'
```

...or, all on one line:

```
echo "a=1 b=2 c=3 a=50" | sed "s/ /\n/g" | perl -e 'my %hash = (); while(<>){ $line = $_; if($line =~ m/(\S+)=(\S+)/) { $hash{$1} = $2; } } for $key (sort keys %hash) { print "$key=$hash{$key}\n"; }'
```